# How to print an array to html text boxs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting one response in my JavaScript function it contains one array named order_quantity. I need to print this array in to ui in same order.

```
<td><input style="width:100px;" type="text" for="order_quantity" id="qty_<?php   echo $i;?>" name="order_quantity[]" class="qty number" ></td>
```

This is my html code. How can I achieve the same.

```
if(valid)
    {
     ajax("indent/indent_api.php",data,function(response)
        { 
        alert(response);

      var result=$.parseJSON(response);
      var array = response;
    //var newHTML = [];
    //rder_quantity = [];
    $.each(array, function(index, value) {
        order_quantity.push('<span>' + value + '</span>');
    });
    $(".element").html(order_quantity.join(""));
```

This is my JavaScript code snippet for handling that particular problem.

Comment: loop through the array and append each value

Comment: @guradio I hope u understant I am new in this. Can you lease suggest some good links for that?

Comment: or use `join()`. It all depends on how you want to display the values.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan I need to print that in text field. and text field is lokks like a column in ui.

Comment: Then show more code. Where is the javascript function you talk about. You only show PHP code. Oh and edit your question, **dont** paste code in a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly kindly find the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to loop through the array and append the data to some html element. For example (using jQuery)

```
$.each(order_quantity[], function(key, value){

  $("#myContainerDiv ul").append("<li>"+value+"</li>");

});
```

Comment: thanks for your valid reply. can you pls tell me more about the mentioned html element. I have added hat I tried before.

Comment: as I'm using `<li>` elements they naturally reside inside an `<ul>` element and I'm specifying it should have an id of `myContainerDiv`, so in this case in the html you'll need an `<ul id = "myContainerDiv"></ul>` and it would get filled up with each of the values from your array.